# How to save from a listbox

Tags: c#, listbox

I am attempting to save items from a listbox to a file; I have tried using things like

- `listbox.items`
- `listbox.items.addrange`
- `listbox.items.count`
- `listbox.items.text` (which doesn't give me an error but it also doesn't save)

Here is code:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (saveFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
   {
       File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, listBox1.Items.Count);
   }
}
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog1.FileName, listBox1.Items.Cast<string>().ToArray());`

Comment: @LarsTech, still outputting a collection, when it expects a string. I doubt this would work.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Do note that I am using `WriteAllLines`.

Comment: @LarsTech, ah excellent point. That would work!

Answer (score 1):

`File.WriteAllText` expects two items: a filepath, and the string to write (as a `String`):

You gave it:

1. ListBox.Items (a collection)
2. ListBox.Items.AddRange (a function)
3. ListBox.Items.Count (Valid, but not related to the actual items because it is just the count)
4. ListBox.Items.Text (what????) (this probably doesn't compile, as I'm not aware of that property)

You need to iterate through all the items, joining them all if you really want to use `File.WriteAllText`.

Something like:

```
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, String.Join(",", listBox1.Items));

//If the above doesn't do the cast implicitly, and its always better to be explicit!
File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, String.Join(",", listBox1.Items.Cast<string>()));
```

[String.Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/57a79xd0%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

There are lots of other ways to generate the output of course, but the short of it is that you need to iterate each element in the `Items` collection and write it out to the file individually, or use a function like `String.Join` to do it all in one go.

Answer (score 0):

You could loop through the items and create a string that contains all of them, then write that string to the file.

```
string itemString = "";
foreach (Item item in listbox1.Items)
{
    itemString+=item.Text;
}

File.WriteAllText(saveFileDialog1.FileName, itemString);
```

You would probably want to add some sort of delimiter with each item, a comma, or a newline character or something so the file doesn't look like gibberish.

Answer (score 0):

To save the items from listBox:

```
private void SaveItems()
{
    using(StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("file.txt"))
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
        {
            sw.WriteLine(listBox1.Items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

To load the items to listBox:

```
private void LoadItems()
{
    using(StreamReader sr = new StreamReader("file.txt"))
    {
        while (!sr.EndOfStream)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(sr.ReadLine());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to store every item in a `ListBox` into a file, it would be best to use [`File.WriteAllLines(String, String[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

```
File.WriteAllLines(saveFileDialog1.FileName, 
    listBox1.Items.OfType<ListViewItem>().Select(i => i.Text).ToArray());
```

Comment: could you tell me which method you are referring to?